# Error when trying to update SharePoint with Access update query

Tags: 2010, access

I manage a SharePoint site, and I use Access queries to update it. I have a basic update query which keeps failing with the error message:

> "There were errors executing the bulk query or sending data to the
>   server. Reconnect the tables to resolve the conflicts or discard the
>   pending changes"

I then have to review conflicts for all the records I am trying to update to reconnect to SharePoint. In the resolve conflicts window it shows my changes against the changes of "Another User", and it shows me that that that other user has made all fields blank.

When I click retry my changes nothing happens and I end up having to discard the changes in order to reconnect the tables to SharePoint.

If anyone could give any advice on how to solve this would be much appreciated. please let me know if you require more information.

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the SharePoint and Office versions you are using